# Recompile Hadoop 2.5.1 native libraries to 32 bit

Tags: hadoop

Phase 1: I have installed Hadoop 2.6.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, I have started it in pseudo-distributed mode and I ran the sample program they [provide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/LibHdfs.html) . Everything ok here.

Phase 2: I have installed Hadoop 2.5.1 on 3 computers that run Ubuntu 10.04 32bit. I have started the HDFS and YARN, I can see them in the web GUI. But when try to compile the same test program I get this:

```
gcc test.c -I$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/include -L/usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_71/jre/lib/amd64/server/  -L$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/native -lhdfs -ljvm -o test
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhdfs.so when searching for -lhdfs
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhdfs.a when searching for -lhdfs
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdfs
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now, when I do `file libhdfs.so.0.0.0` , I get :

```
libhdfs.so.0.0.0:   ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

So, the native libraries are 64bit and my OS is 32bit.

Question:
Is it necessary to recompile entire Hadoop from source or can I only recompile native libraries and replace them in the existing installation?
What is the shortest path ?

Please provide info on recompilation.

**Edit:**

I have compiled for 32bit on my 64bit machine, I've exported CLFAGS=-m32 , but I had this error :

```
[exec] /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
     [exec] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
     [exec] make[2]: *** [target/usr/local/lib/libhdfs.so.0.0.0] Error 1
     [exec] make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hdfs.dir/all] Error 2
```

What I did next was to manually install and configure update-alternatives to point java8 JDK 32bit.

I only had a problem with libfuse-dev, which I have uninstalled.
Since it was not mandatory.

After that I ran : `mvn package -Pnative -DskipTests -Dtar`

and found the libs here : `hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target/native/target/usr/local/lib` :

```
libhdfs.a  libhdfs.so  libhdfs.so.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recent hadoop tarballs only seem to ship with 64 bit libraries. You can compile them yourself, altough i haven't tested this myself.
You will have to download the source tarball of hadoop and install the following packages:

- GCC (or another C compiler)
- GNU Autotools (autoconf, automake, libtool)
- zlib dev package
- openssl dev package
- maven

Once this is installed you can use the standard hadoop pom.xml file contained in the source tarball to compile the native libraries:

```
$ mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dtar
```

The libraries can be found in:

```
$ hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-2.6.0/lib/native
```

The bin/hadoop script ensures the native hadoop library is on the classpath via the system property -Djava.library.path. You can modify the bin/hadoop script to point to your newly compiled libraries. For more information be sure to check the documentation that is available [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html).

Comment: I have an error, I've been trying to install java8 for i386 but with no luck .. I shall try one more time manually, if that does not work... I will need to create a virtual machine for 32bit. It works for 64 bit .

Comment: java 8 is not supported yet by hadoop. Use java 7, for a list of recommended java versions look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopJavaVersions)